# Facebook Sharer doesn't grab thumbnail image

Tags: php, facebook

my Facebook sharer doesn't grab my Thumbnail image:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s= 100&amp;p[title]=TEST&amp;p[url]=TEST&amp;p[images][0]=TEST&amp;p[summary]=TEST
```

It won't fetch the image I enter there. Am I doing something wrong?

**Ok, it looks like FB requires the image in 356x200 Pixels!**
Solved!

Comment: Do you have og:image on your site?

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

[http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=TEST&p[url]=TEST&p[images][0]=http://wallalay.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Grumpy-Cat-79.jpg&p[summary]=TEST](http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Btitle%5D=TEST&p%5Burl%5D=TEST&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=http://wallalay.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Grumpy-Cat-79.jpg&p%5Bsummary%5D=TEST)

Try to check if your image is accessible from the internet. For example check that:

- the image is not published under localhost
- if you're using IIS make sure you enable anonymous authentication.